# Install oozie's sharedlib cloudera

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-manager

I have problems trying to install a new CDH5 cluster with cloudera. Using parcels everything goes fine except when oozie's sharedlib is installed. It fails uploading due to end of time-out.

Then I tried using packages but is worse. The cluster install fails downloading packages: "Operation too slow... trying another mirror... no more mirrors to try... giving up"

> Downloading Packages: 
>   http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/redhat/6/x86_64/cdh/5/RPMS/noarch/bigtop-utils-0.7.0%2Bcdh5.2.0%2B0-1.cdh5.2.0.p0.40.el6.noarch.rpm:
>   [Errno 12] Timeout on
>   http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/redhat/6/x86_64/cdh/5/RPMS/noarch/bigtop-utils-0.7.0%2Bcdh5.2.0%2B0-1.cdh5.2.0.p0.40.el6.noarch.rpm:
>   (28, 'Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30
>   seconds')  Trying other mirror.
>
> Error Downloading Packages: 
>   bigtop-utils-0.7.0+cdh5.2.0+0-1.cdh5.2.0.p0.40.el6.noarch: failure:
>   RPMS/noarch/bigtop-utils-0.7.0+cdh5.2.0+0-1.cdh5.2.0.p0.40.el6.noarch.rpm
>   from cloudera-cdh5: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
>
> END (1)  remote package bigtop-utils could not be installed, giving up

I just need to install HDFS, Hue and, of course, its dependencies. Do you know what could be the reason of the time-out error? Maybe it has something to do with the cloudera servers and that today are slow.

Also, is there any other way to install oozie's sharedlib as a workaround of this?

**UPDATE:**

At the time of writing this I could install the cluster, via parcels, correctly. Anyway, I would like to know the answer to this questions.

Comment: The Internet was not cooperating?

Comment: The internet is fine in my side, I don't know the status of the cloudera servers.

Comment: I been almost 24h trying to install the cluster, now it seems to be working but I would like to know if there's another way to install the sharedlib of Oozie.